# How to run a SQL statement every time a row is created?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are using an ERP system which uses SQL Server. There is a function which creates a row 'A' in a specific table and populates it with data from another row 'B' of another table. For some reason the programmer thought, one would need only certain values of 'B' in 'A'. So only the values of some columns in 'B' are copied.

Now I want more columns to be copied than the program copies. The columns are there but they don't get copied.

The program offers a way to run a script before the SQL statement, which creates the row, is executed. So the problem here is, I don't know the id of the row which will be created. And even if I would, the row isn't created yet to alter it.

Is there a way in SQL Server to run a SQL script every time after a row is created in a specific table?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: First clarify what do you mean under dataset, tables, fields, creating datasets, populating datasets etc.

Comment: Can't you just modify the original function to copy the new fields...?

Comment: replaced dataset with row

Comment: sadly i cannot modify the original function.

Comment: Take a variable `rowCreated`. Make rowCreated = 1 whenever row is created in specific table. then if (rowCreated == 1) fire the function which will run the another sql script.

Comment: if you tell me where and how to do that in mssql

Comment: Look for `AFTER INSERT TRIGGERS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - those are called **triggers**.

You can write triggers that get fired after `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` - or they can be `INSTEAD OF` triggers, too - if you need to completely take control of an operation.

In your case, I believe an `AFTER INSERT` trigger should be just fine:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TrgCopyAdditionalColumns
ON dbo.TableA
AFTER INSERT 
AS  
    -- the newly inserted row (there could be **multiple!**)
    -- will be stored in the `Inserted` pseudo table, which has the 
    -- exact same structure as your "TableB" table - just pick out
    -- the columns you need to insert into "TableA" from here
    INSERT INTO dbo.TableA (Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
       SELECT 
           b.Col1, b.Col2, ..., b.ColN
       FROM 
           dbo.TableB AS b
       INNER JOIN
           -- somehow, you need to connect your Table B's rows to the
           -- newly inserted rows for Table A that are present in the 
           -- "Inserted" pseudo table, to get only those rows of data from
           -- Table B that are relevant to the newly inserted Table A rows
           Inserted i ON b.A_ID = i.ID
```

Comment: since i have to copy from 'B' to 'A' i assume i do have to insert my value from 'B' into the pseudo table

Comment: @Cheetah: updated my response. You need to somehow associate the rows from Table B that you grab additional columns from with the newly inserted rows in Table A (that are present in the `Inserted` pseudo table) - can't know how that connection is made, I just hinted at something that you need to figure out

Comment: Got a new. Problem now. Wanted to create the trigger but there is already an Insertion Trigger. It has a little lock on its icon and i cannot edit the trigger. is there a way to place mine after the existing one or to alter it anyway.

Comment: @Cheetah: that "lock" indicates that the trigger is *encrypted*, so you cannot inspect it's code. But there can definitely be *multiple* triggers of the same type on a table - no problem. You cannot easily control the *order of execution* of those triggers, however - write your trigger in such a way that it doesn't matter if it's executed first or after the other trigger